# Modelagem do banco com classes com relacionamento de n para n

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, entidade-relacionamento

Galera Bom dia.

Estou fazendo a modelagem de uma empresa que possui varias filiais.
Basicamente tenho informações, de porte, do organograma de cada porte, e de cargos na filiais.

Por Exemplo

Porte: Pequeno 1, Pequeno 2 , médio, grande, ...

Item Organograma: Direção, Markting, Vendas, Logistica, Gerencia ...

Cargo: Diretor, Secretaria, Gerente, Vendedor, Entregador, Co-adjunto...

O problema basicamente é esse.

Cada filial da empresa tem um porte. Um porte pode ter vários itens do organograma (por exemplo se a unidade for de pequeno porte 1 pode ter apenas o item do organograma de vendas, se for de pequeno 2 pode ter  gerencia e vendas, se for media pode ter direção, gerencia e vendas, etc.. ), e um item do organograma pode está ligado a vários portes (por exemplo, direção pode está em pequeno a grande, já gerência pode está apenas em médio e grande porte, etc..). Um item organograma pode está relacionado a outro, por exemplo, tenho direção como pai e debaixo de direcao tenho gerencia e markting, e debaixo de markting tenho vendas e assim por diante. Cada cargo está ligado a um item organograma, que pode ter um ou mais (p.ex: No organograma de direção posso ter o cargo de diretor e secretaria), bem como cada item pode ter um ou mais cargo. E os cargos estão ligados as filiais, uma filial pode ter vários cargos, e posso ter do mesmo cargo em varias filiais, porém o cargo não esta ligado ao porte em si, por exemplo posso ter o cargo de secretária no organograma de direção de uma filial de pequeno porte, porém talvez não tenha cargo de secretaria de direção em uma filial de médio, ou seja depende de cada unidade.

Fiz uma modelagem no Astah [image: Essa].
Porém não sei se está correta, e a partir dela(ou da correta), como modelaria o banco (Usando o mysql).

[image: Organograma]

Answer (score 0):

Não está correcto, _rel_organograma_de_porte, tem uma ligação a ir de si para si mesmo, apaga isso por favor. Se variáveis estão ligadas, tens de fazer uma tabela à parte. Quando a ligação é de 'n' para 'n', cria também uma tabela intermédia que vai guardar os valores mas com diferentes ids.
Ficando [Porte] n ---- 1 [TABELA AUXILIAR] 1 ---- n [item_organograma].
Por fim, não convém existirem ligações em "T" uma linha tracejada não se separa em 2, faz as ligações independentes.

Exemplo de um bom modelo de dados: [Bom exemplo](http://www.funpar.ufpr.br:8080/rup/process/modguide/images/md_dmdl3.gif)

Comment: Então teria de ter outa tabela de relacionamento de organograma de porte para organograma de porte? Outra coisa não entendi a questão da ligação em "T", como assim fazer independente? Você quer dizer que as classes não tem relacionamento de associação?

Comment: Sim à primeira pergunta, quanto à segunda pergunta, têm de ter relacionamento sim. Só estava a dizer para pores as tabelas com as diferentes ligações, isto é, a _rel_organograma_de_porte, ficava um uma ligação para Porte e outra ligação para item_organograma, mas independentes. Duas linhas separadas. E estabelece se as classes ficam todas com letra Grande no início, para teres alguma homogeneidade.